# UITextView content size not increasing in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitextview

I created a UITextView and set the `isScrollEnabled` to true, after I paste two lines text in the textView, then I input the text by keyboard, but the textView's `contentSize` did not increase, it only happened in iOS 8 and only after I paste two lines text.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        updateCommentViewHeight(45.0)
    } else {
        let height = calculateTextSize(with: textView).height  //calulate textview height by content text
        updateCommentViewHeight(height + 30.0)
        if commentInputView.bounds.height > height + 29.0 {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

private func updateCommentViewHeight(_ height: CGFloat) {
    constrain(commentInputView, replace: group, block: { (commentInputView) in
        commentInputView.height == height
    })
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: @lamOwenHong, please post more code for `commentInputView` and so on.

Comment: @aircraft commentInputView is a custom UIView, it contains a UITextView and the UITextView's constraints is offset 10px  to commentInputView .

Comment: I mean you should post more code or storyboard imagescreen, such as `updateCommentViewHeight` method code, so we can convenience test it.

Comment: @aircraft, thank you, I just update the question